# Spring Cloud Stream - publish and consume from same queue with same routing key with different headers

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

**Producer**

```
exchange name : xyz,
exchange type: direct,
queue: myqueue,
routingkey : myroutingkey,
```

producer can send different Types of Object to the queue but to distinguish b/w the objects he will send header['type'] = 'type1' along with 'myroutingkey' which is already binded withe queue.

```
send message  : myroutingkey + header[type] = type1 to queue: 
myqueue

send message : myroutingkey + header[type] = type2 to queue: 
myqueue
```

**Consumer**

```
@StreamListner1 - consume type1 message from queue: 
myqueue with routingkey : myroutingkey

@StreamListner2 - consume type2 message from queue: 
myqueue with routingkey : myroutingkey
```

I am using Rabit MQ to achieve above requirement.

The above requirement is possible to do with spring cloud stream.if it is possible what need to do the publisher and consumer side.give me some example.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by using `condition` attribute on `@StreamListener`. For example,

```
@StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='bogey'")
```

The details are [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.0.RC3/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing).

Comment: Bear in mind that will only work if both listeners are in the same application. Consumers don't have any notion of routing key. Publishers publish to an exchange with a routing key; consumers consume from a queue bound to the exchange with a routing key. 2 consumers for the same queue will compete for messages. If you want 2 `@StreamListener`s in different applications to get a subset of messages published by publisher, each consumer needs its own queue bound with the appropriate routing key.